# Why user_permissions does not return any thing?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my scenario:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.model import Permission, Group
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 

user = get_user_model().objects.create(email='example@google.com')


group = Group.objects.create(name='group1')
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
    app_label=get_user_model()._meta.app_label, 
    model=get_user_model()._meta.model_name
)
permission = Permission.objects.create(
    name='perm1', 
    codename='perm1', 
    content_type=content_type
)

group.permissions.add(permission)
user.groups.add(group)
```

**Question:**
So why this query doesn't have any results:

```py
user.user_permissions.all()
```

**Output**

```
<QuerySet []>
```

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user_permissions is many-to-many relationship to Permission (auth_permission table). Group permissions stored in auth_group_permission table.

**get_user_permissions(obj=None)**

Returns a set of permission strings that the user has directly.

**get_group_permissions(obj=None)**

Returns a set of permission strings that the user has, through their groups.

**get_all_permissions(obj=None)**

Returns a set of permission strings that the user has, both through group and user permissions.